# Android sdkmanager was found, but failed to run

Tags: flutter, android-studio, environment-variables

I am beginning my journey into Flutter but am running into some problems with the setup. I believe I have the most recent version of the everything I need on Android Studio, but am running into some issues. I also just recently downloaded a newer version of Java. Here is the CLI error message I am receiving:

```
java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\Name\Flutter>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run
(C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Here are screenshots of my SDK's and Environment Variables:

Android API 34

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I was 100% confident everything was updated and there were no issues. As a last resort, I uninstalled Android Studio and Reinstalled it, with the exact same options checked. This seemed to do the trick.